# Indexing ones into a matrix of zeros without loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I'm fairly new to MATLAB and I need some help with this problem.

the problem is to write a function that creates an (n-n) square matrix of zeros with ones on the reverse diagonal 
I tried this code:

```
function s=reverse_diag(n)
    s=zeros(n);
    i=1;j=n;
    while i<=n && j>=1
        s(i,j)=1;
        i=i+1;
        j=j-1;
    end
```

but I want another way for solving it without using loops  or diag and eye commands.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to solve it without diag and eye commands?

Comment: Hint: see the result of `bsxfun(@eq, 1:n, (1:n).')`. Try to understand how it works and turn it into your desired output

Comment: Thanks Luis I'm searching to find how it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most obvious way to achieve this without loops would be to use

```
s=fliplr(eye(n))
```

since you stated that you don't want to use eye (for whatever reason), you could also work with `sub2ind`-command. It would look like this:

```
s=zeros(n);
s(sub2ind(size(s),1:size(s,1),size(s,2):-1:1))=1
```

Comment: Thank you max ...that is exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: @RuneKnight You're welcome. If you're trying to get used to vectorization in matlab, you should also consider dealing with Luis Mendos comment, since `bsxfun` is an awesome tool for that.

Comment: I'm currently researching how this command works ...but what to do you mean by vectorization ?

Comment: @RuneKnight have a look at the vectorization-tag description: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vectorization/info. Vectorization means using funtions on whole arrays instead of looping through the array.